# Calling an assembly language function causes "floating point stack check" exception

Tags: delphi, assembly, x86

Executing following code:

```
function ABCD32(Value: Cardinal): Single; register;
asm
  BSWAP  EAX
end;

function HexToFloat(hexValue: string; fmt: THexFloatFormat): Single;
var
  c: Cardinal;
  Err: Integer;
begin
  Result := NaN;
  c := HexToCardinal(hexValue, Err); //DCBA format
  if Err <> 0 then Exit();
  case fmt of
    hfABCD: Result := ABCD32(c); //Here, after return from ABCD32
    hfBADC: Result := BADC32(c);
    hfCDAB: Result := CDAB32(c);
    hfDCBA: Result := DCBA32(c);
  end;
end;
```

causes a run-time errror:

> Project HexFloat.exe raised exception class $C0000092 with message 'floating point stack check at 0x004e9903'.

What is this and how to handle it?

**Update**

Here is the CPU window output:

```
HexFloat.dpr.162: hfABCD: Result := ABCD32(c);
004E98F8 8B45F0           mov eax,[ebp-$10]
004E98FB E894FFFFFF       call ABCD32
004E9900 D95DF4           fstp dword ptr [ebp-$0c] //WTF?
004E9903 9B               wait //Exception happens here
004E9904 EB28             jmp $004e992e
```

Comment: The return value of a float type is passed on the fpu stack.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your function does not respect the ABI. Floating point values should be returned in ST(0) on the x87 unit.

```
function ABCD32(Value: Cardinal): Single; register;
asm
  BSWAP  EAX
  PUSH   EAX
  FLD    [ESP]
  ADD    ESP,4
end;
```

Comment: @J... thank you. David: well... I'm not sure what to think of future people reading about windows, so I rather deleted my comments, and I will follow on that separate question. Thank you for your input in the discussion and for having patience with me. ;)

Comment: @Ped7g Thanks. I appreciate that.  And it was good to think about this, I'm very pleased to have learnt something.